# After login, show HTTP Status 403

Tags: orbeon

I tried to use orbeon default login page to login (i.e. http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/auth?source=/fr/).  After login successfully, it showed the tomcat error page "HTTP Status 403".  After that, I manually input the URL http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/ and found the account has been already login.  Why didn't the page redirect to /fr/ after login? Is some setting missing?

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that you are on the Form Runner home page `/fr/`, click on the user icon at the top-right of the page, then click *Login*. You are sent to `/fr/auth?source=/fr/`. There you enter your login/password, and hit the *Login* button. What is the URL you are sent next? Could you also include a screenshot of that page? And what servlet container are you using; is it Tomcat or something else? ‑Alex

Comment: Yes.  But no next page found after entered login/password and click Login button.  Still stay at URL /fr/auth?source=/fr/ but show error as above picture.  I am using Tomcat 9 as servlet container.

Comment: Got it @hkcad, then I've gave it a shot, and provided an answer below. You'll let me know if this help. ‑Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're getting this error when the user logs in successfully *and* that user doesn't have access to that page. If you think the user should have access the page, I'd check that the user has a role that you require in the `web.xml` (out-of-the-box, that would be the `orbeon-user` role).

Comment: Bingo.  You are right. In my case, the login user has a custom role.  So, I need to add this custom role as role-name in the security-constraint for url-pattern `/fr/auth` in web.xml.  After that, the login page can do the redirection after login.  Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Excellent @hkcad, I'm glad putting matching roles solved the issue, and thank you for the update. ‑Alex